# How to remove row in UITableViewController presented as popover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewController` that I present as a popover in my app. In some of the cells there is a delete button (trash can) to remove that item. Everything works as it should except that I the UI is not update when pressing the delete button. That is, the data is cleared and I call `self.tableView.reloadData()`, but the cell remains visible in the UI. (Pressing the delete button again makes the app crash in my C++ code because of an assert). I have no storyboard or xib as I do not need it. I only want this to be in code.

What am I missing? It might be something simple, but I cannot fathom why. I have tried:

- Separate data source implementation.
- Calling `reloadData()` both sync and async.
- Setting delegate to self.
- Various other hacks.

Here is the `UITableViewController` implementation:

```
import Foundation

class IngredientInfoPopoverViewController : UITableViewController
{
    var slViewController: ShoppingListViewController?;
    var ingredientName: String = "Ingrediens";
    @IBOutlet var uniqueIngredients: [Ingredient] = []; // Unique per *recipe* so that we can list all the recipes for the ingredients
    var clickedCellIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil;

    enum SECTIONS : Int
    {
        case HEADER = 0;
        case RECIPE = 1;
    }

    static let ROW_HEIGHT = 44;

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OpenIngredientInfoCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OpenIngredientInfoCell");
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OpenRecipeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OpenRecipeCell");

        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine;
        tableView.bounces = false; // "Static" table view
        updateSize();
    }

    func updateSize()
    {
        let totalCount = min(uniqueIngredients.count + 1, 6); // + 1: header row. min: Allow max 5 recipes in list (enables scrolling)
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: totalCount * IngredientInfoPopoverViewController.ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    func setup(slvc: ShoppingListViewController?, ingredients: [Ingredient], clickedCellIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.slViewController = slvc;
        self.clickedCellIndexPath = clickedCellIndexPath;

        if (ingredients.count > 0)
        {
            let first = ingredients[0];
            for i in ingredients
            {
                assert(i.getId() == first.getId());
            }

            ingredientName = first.getName();
            var uniqueRecipeNames: Set<String> = [];
            for i in ingredients
            {
                uniqueRecipeNames.insert(i.getRecipeName());
            }

            let sorted = uniqueRecipeNames.sorted();
            uniqueIngredients.removeAll();
            for s in sorted
            {
                for i in ingredients
                {
                    if (i.getRecipeName() == s)
                    {
                        uniqueIngredients.append(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        switch section
        {
        case SECTIONS.HEADER.rawValue:
            return 1;
        case SECTIONS.RECIPE.rawValue:
            return uniqueIngredients.count;
        default:
            assert(false);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
        case SECTIONS.HEADER.rawValue:
            assert(indexPath.row == 0);
            if (uniqueIngredients.count > 0)
            {
                let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[0]; // All are the same ingredient
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                slViewController?.onIngredientInfoButtonClicked(ingredient);
            }
            break;

        case SECTIONS.RECIPE.rawValue:
            if (indexPath.row < uniqueIngredients.count)
            {
                let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[indexPath.row];
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                slViewController?.onRecipeInfoButtonClicked(ingredient);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell();

        switch (indexPath.section)
        {
        case SECTIONS.HEADER.rawValue:
            if (uniqueIngredients.count > 0)
            {
                let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[0];
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenIngredientInfoCell", for: indexPath) as! OpenIngredientInfoCell;
                cell.setup(ingredient);
            }
            break;

        case SECTIONS.RECIPE.rawValue:
            if (indexPath.row < uniqueIngredients.count)
            {
                cell.selectionStyle = .none; // Without this the cell contents become gray and disappear when long pressing! FML
                let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[indexPath.row];
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenRecipeCell", for: indexPath) as! OpenRecipeCell;
                cell.setup(self, ingredient, clickedCellIndexPath);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return cell;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(IngredientInfoPopoverViewController.ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    func ingredientRemoved(_ ingredient: Ingredient)
    {
        for i in 0..<uniqueIngredients.count
        {
            if (uniqueIngredients[i].getRecipeId() == ingredient.getRecipeId())
            {
                uniqueIngredients.remove(at: i);
//              let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: SECTIONS.RECIPE.rawValue);
//              self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade);
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (uniqueIngredients.count == 0)
        {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I present the `IngredientInfoPopoverViewController`:

```
@objc func ingredientInfoClicked(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation)!

    let ingredients = CppInterface.shoppingList.getIngredients(UInt(indexPath.section), position: UInt(indexPath.row));

    let controller = IngredientInfoPopoverViewController();
    controller.setup(slvc: self, ingredients: ingredients!, clickedCellIndexPath: indexPath);
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover;
    controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self;
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData();
    });
}
```

Here is how the view controller looks when presented. If I click the trash can on one of the items, the data is cleared, but the cell is not removed from the UI, which is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: How the view controller is presented]

Comment: That's weird indeed. Code looks OK, yet it almost looks like your datasource isn't getting update. What if when you delete an ingredient you set empty the datasource completely and then reload the tableview i.e. `uniqueIngredients = []; tableView.reloadData();`? Just to confirm that `reloadData()` is getting called and the right datasource is being updated...

Comment: You probably should post your delegate code - both for `UITableViewDelegate` along with the popover's delegate for the datasource. Without that? Maybe try putting breakpoints in your delegate code to make sure they are getting executed.

Comment: @dfd The `UITableViewController` is itself a `UITableViewDelegate`, so the code is already posted. Unless I misunderstand you? Both `numberOfSections()` and `numberOfRowsInSection()` are called as expected, both before and after deleting an ingredient. `cellForRowAt()` is called 3 times before deleting an ingredient and 2 times after, both correct.

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I tried doing `uniqueIngredients = []; tableView.reloadData(); return;` and nothing more when deleting an ingredient. The popover UI freezes, except that I can still click all the UI elements as before. Clicking the delete buttons again makes the app crash because the underlying data is invalid. Clicking on the side of the popover dismisses it, which it should. I tested on iPhone 6 (iOS 12) and iPhone 11 Simulator (iOS 13) and the behavior is the same. Something is definitely off with that `reloadData()` call.

Comment: @Krøllebølle that's definitely a weird error. How about you create an entirely new project, with just a tableview controller, a datasource, delete button on the cells, and similar delete functionality. So if it works on this new app, then it's probably something small you're doing wrong, in which case, just remove the entire code, copy the new code from working app, and amend it step-by-step

Comment: Just created a mock app, and I think I've figured out where you're going wrong. It's in your `cellForRowAt` function. I'll post an answer for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually surprised your `tableView` shows any data at all. Because you declare `cell` as a `let` in `cellForRowAt` when you do `let cell = UITableViewCell();`, that makes it immutable, and the first `cell` (outside of the `switch`) is the one that should technically get returned. Hence why no data should be displaying. And probably also the reason why your `tableView` is not updating correctly.

Anyway, you should only declare `cell` when you're dequeueing it, and you should as much as possible, avoid force-unwrapping of a variable.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == SECTIONS.HEADER.rawValue, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenIngredientInfoCell", for: indexPath) as? OpenIngredientInfoCell {
        // not sure this check is necessary, but I'm adding it because it was in your original code
        guard uniqueIngredients.count > 0 else { return UITableViewCell() }
        let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[0]
        cell.setup(ingredient)
        return cell

    } else if indexPath.section == SECTIONS.RECIPE.rawValue, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenRecipeCell", for: indexPath) as? OpenRecipeCell {
        // it shouldn't be possible for the indexPath to ever be greater than the dataSource items count, but I'll keep the check
        guard indexPath.row < uniqueIngredients.count else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let ingredient = uniqueIngredients[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(self, ingredient, clickedCellIndexPath)
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

- I've removed the `semi-colons` as they're not necessary in Swift.
- For specifying the table cells' reuse identifiers, using the class names would probably be better. So you would use `"\(OpenRecipeCell.self)"` instead of `"OpenRecipeCell"`

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the strangeness of the let outside the switch that did it (together with redeclaring it later). This type of code originates from my mind being C++ centric and normally writing code that can easily be Return Value Optimized, though one have to do it correctly. Not sure if the Swift compiler even does that. (My brain also like semicolons because of C++, I cannot decide whether or not I want to use it in Swift).

Comment: No semi-colons is where most languages are moving towards, so if you'll be working with other languages, might be a good idea to pick it up. Also, with Swift, you can declare the variable in advance `let cell: UITableViewCell`, so long as you make sure to instantiate it later on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the defaulted way of editing a `UITableView` (either swiping or entering edit mode), then here's my delegate code that works fine:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedStep = appState.recipe.steps[sourceIndexPath.row]
    appState.recipe.steps.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    appState.recipe.steps.insert(movedStep, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        appState.recipe.steps.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tblSteps.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I manually place this table view in edit mode through a `UIBarButtonItem`, and a cell can *both* be moved or deleted.
- My data source is in my model, at `appState.recipe.steps`. The structure doesn't matter, just handling the array.
- I set a `Notification` anytime this array is changed that triggers a `reloadData()` in this table view.

I don't see either of these delegate methods listed, so I'm posting this answer. If by chance it doesn't help you, I'll gladly delete this.